Uppercase “God” in translations of Greek plays
A few months ago I read Fagles' translation of Oedipus Rex, Oedipus at Colonus, and Antigone. I've just started to read Fitts and Fitzgerald's translation of the same. In both translations I was thrown off by their writing "God" (capital, like the Christian deity) in some passages — since I don't think Sophocles could have had a monotheistic god in mind. For example:

By weight of age, as I am a priest of God.


Yet we have come to you to make our prayer 
As to the man surest in mortal ways 
And wisest in the ways of God.


Yet whenever he comes back, I should do ill 
To scant whatever duty God reveals.


So, with the help of God, 
We shall be saved — or else indeed we are lost.

These are all from the first ten pages of Fitts and Fitzgerald's translation. There are fewer in Fagles, but:

tell them we'll do everything. God help us, 
we will see our triumphs — or our fall.

(lines 163–165)

even if god had never urged you on to act,

(line 291)

they bring him on at last, the seer, the man of god.

(line 339, also in line 368 “the word of god”, 371 “the love of god”)
How should I interpret all of these passages? Do I just need a more “modern” (not that these ought to be old) translation?

Especially in older English, I recall occasionally seeing nouns of specific importance being capitalized against today's common conventions. I can't judge whether that phenomenon alone is enough to explain what you see, though. Christians don't have a unique privilege to using a capital G.

Of course, in the first Fagles passage that you cite, the word begins a sentence; so it would be capitalized anyway. Are there other instances where the word is capitalized?

There are two things going on here.
One, sometimes the translators are being liberal with their translations, such as your first example.

οἱ δὲ σὺν γήρᾳ βαρεῖς,
ἱερῆς, ἐγὼ μὲν Ζηνός

As you can see, the word that Fagles translates as "God" is actually "Zeus" (in the genitive).
That said, you do see a singular θεός used in Greek where English translators often (but not always) translate with "God." This is typical when there's not a specific deity in mind. It functions like a collective, general, or even indefinite noun. It's just another way of saying "the gods" or "some god", perhaps sometimes even referring to a Zeus or another god that has already been named.
This should never be mistaken as a sign of monotheism. In the texts you get this singular "God", you also see references to "gods" and the wide variety of many of other gods. It even appears in the works of Homer, sometimes adjacent to Zeus (such as θεὸς Ζεύς in the Odyssey, 4.236), sometimes bare.
You get this sometimes in Latin, too, e.g. in Ovid's Metamorphoses (10.586): audentes deus ipse iuvat, "God helps the daring." This doesn't mean that Ovid believed in a singular god, and that case is bolstered by similar variations on the cliche in which Fortuna is more explicitly stated as she who iuvat.
Whether to capitalize the word or not is purely a matter of English and has nothing to do with the Greek (or Latin). Early Greek lacked a distinction between upper case and lower case letters, and so the choice to employ one is always a matter of interpretation and application of later, i.e. English rules.

"This should never be mistaken as a sign of monotheism" only in the plays, or also in e.g. Neo-Platonist philosophy, which certainly seem to hew closer towards that than Homer and later playwrites?

@Tristan I'm in particular referring to Classical Greek thought, but I do give a rundown on monotheistic tendencies among some Greek philosophers here.

I've just pulled out my copy of Sophocles' Theban Plays, translated by E. F Watling, Penguin Classics. I'll paraphrase his notes on names of deities.

"God": the "great invisible source of moral law or unseen arbiter of human destiny". "That order did not come from God"
"The gods" is more anthropic: "only the gods have deathless life".
"The god", for a reference to a particular deity "Whatever the god requires, it shall be done". I expect that your example of the seer would refer to a prophet of Apollo, and we know how badly Apollo stuffed up with Orestes.
"A god/some god" one of an indeterminate range of nameless power, mostly of evil. "Some god must have made you do it".

